# Lua get value of a table in n tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a problem,
I must change a value in a known table which is located in `n` tables before.
Something like this:

```
Box = {
        {Name = "",Box = {{Name = "",Box = {{Name = "", Box = {{Name = "This must be change for the test",Box = {}}}}}}}}
    }
```

To change this I can hardcode this with:

```
Box[1].Box[1].Box[1].Box[1].Name = "Changed"
```

But this isn't the way I want it!
I want to change this dynamically, so that I have one function which can change the value `'x'` of table `'n'` in the main table `'tbl'`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `local t, n = _G, 4; for j = 1, n do t = t.Box[1] end; t.Name = "Changed"`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, this should be enough for the answer; I measured ;)

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - But it nicely fits in one-line-comment !  :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Its a good answer! Thank you for that now. But what is if a box has 2 of the same tables? Is there any other way to set this. 
like `Box[1].Box[5].Box[2].Box[3].Name = "Changed"`

Comment: @YoungFlyme - Do you know the sequence `1, 5, 2, 3` beforehand?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ofcourse, I had the idea to save all needed ID's in a table and access via your loop to them like:
`local t, n = _G, #ID; for j = 1, n do t = t.Box[ID[j]] end; t.Name = "Changed"`

Answer (score 0):

With the problem like that you probably should rethink your design choices. That table in n tables, you describe is akin to a tree graph where field `box` holds the references to children nodes.

As your comments state, you have the need of modifying a node located on a dynamic path in that tree. A simple function is obvious:

```
local function follow_path(start_node, path,i)
  --takes start node and array of indices to follow
  --returns table that is stored in the box-tree at this path
  --i is for internal recursion
  i=i or 1
  if not path[i] then 
    return start_node
  else
    local new_start=start[path[i]]
    assert(new_start,"No node is on this path")
    return follow_path(new_start,path,i+1)
  end
end
local function follow_path_and_rename(start_node,path,field_name,new_value)
  local box = follow_path( start_node,path)
  box[field_name] = new_value
end
```

But, depending on why do you need to modify a node with dynamic path there might be more solid approaches. One thing that never hurts is to give each of your boxes a unique identifier during its creation:

```
local new_box
do
 local box_count=0
 new_box = function(name)
  box_count=box_count+1
  local box = { 
   unique_id=box_count,
   name=name,
   box={}
  }
  return box
 end
end
```

With that you could for example create index table where your boxes are always accessible by their id:

```
local index={}
local add_new_box = function(name)
  local box = new_box(name)
  index[ box.unique_id] = box
  return box
end
```

Or if that is unacceptable, you could always search through the nodes of tree for a node that is guaranteed to have unique value.

But the thing is: all the tables do already have unique identifier. It is their address, the value that gets assigned to `a` when you do `a = {}`. The only differences between that, and the `unique_id` are: 
1)`a` is not quite as readable. 
2) if you know `a`, you don't need to search for it.

So, take a look at your problem, take a look and ask yourself: 
"Where this need comes from? Why cannot I get `unique_id` instead a sequence of indices? Why cannot I get the `box` itself instead of `unique_id`?"